# Error in creating a controller file

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework. I have tried everything, searching and adding keys but I[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y69Cz.png) cannot understand what the problem is and how to resolve it.

```
 public class Reservation
{
    [Key]
    public int BookingID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public int RoomID { get; set; }
    public string BookingDate { get; set; }
    public int Check_In { get; set; }
    public int Check_Out { get; set; }
    public int Adults { get; set; }
    public int Children { get; set; }
    public int NoOfNights { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RoomID")]
    public virtual Room Rooms { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CustomerID")]
    public virtual CustomerDetails CustomerDetail { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Payment> Payment { get; set; }
}


 public class CustomerDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int PostCode { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeF51.png)

Comment: Are you really sure that all entities have a primary key? How did you set up those primary keys, by an entity type configuration or by data atributes?

Comment: I don't know how to describe it to you. I have made model classes. In which i have given a [key] attribute to them.

Comment: a Key attribute is a DataAttribute. The error says that there is a lot of entities that dont have a Key attribute in an Id property (or other key property name)

Comment: if possible then show some model classes as a example.

Comment: Show us some code

Comment: What does your context look like?

Comment: context and model classes above ^

Comment: No context there. Do you have a context at all?

Answer (score 0):

All tables need a primary key or you can't use Entity Framework.